# cpulimit of a given process

Tags: cpu-usage, bash

I'm running the windows version of Tribler using wine in Ubuntu 10.10. Some times it eats a lot of power of my cpu and causes my laptop to heat up. So I need to slowdown Tribler, and I discovered `cpulimit`. To run `cpulimit` you need to use the `PID` number of the process. So I managed to do the following in `.bashrc`:

```
alias tribler='wine /home/my_home/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Tribler/tribler.exe'
alias slowdowntribler="cpulimit -l 10 -p `ps -ef | grep 'tribler.exe' | grep -vw 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'`"
alias slowtribler='tribler; slowdowntribler'
```

The alias `tribler` just run the windows version of Tribler using `wine`.
The alias `slowdowntribler` just run `cpulimit` using the `PID` of the process whose name is `Tribler.exe`.

It is assumed that the third alias first run `tribler` so `Tribler.exe` goes up, and then `slowdowntribler` to limit the cpu usage of Tribler. But a problem arises here. This last alias will run `slowdowntribler` after I quit (or kill) `Tribler.exe`. To solve this I have tried:

```
alias slowtribler='tribler&; slowdowntribler'
```

(and some variations) but I get the following error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `;' and it should work as expected.

**EDIT**
To summarize the discussion, the working code is

```
alias tribler='wine /home/my_home/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Tribler/tribler.exe'
alias slowdowntribler='cpulimit -l 10 -p `ps -ef | grep "tribler.exe" | grep -vw "grep" | awk "{print \\$2}"`'
alias slowtribler='tribler& sleep 1; slowdowntribler'
```

It might be required to use another argument in the `sleep` call (eg. 5).

Comment: It doesn't. In that case cpulimit fails to get the PID, and so it fails to limit the cpu usage.

Comment: And what is the result of `tribler& sleep 1; slowdowntribler`?

Comment: the problem seems to be that in some way the command `slowdowntrilber` must be executed after `tribler` properly uploaded `Tribler.exe` into the list of running programs. It works if I execute both commands at hand in the console, but if I run `tribler& slowdowntribler`, then `slowdowntribler` executes before `tribler` and the PID is not passed to `slowdowntribler`.

Comment: Well, I think you're right... `tribler` is executed just before `slowdowntribler` is executed, thus `wine` has not yet uploaded the process to the list, so `slowdowntribler` cannot find it. Thus I proposed to use `sleep 1`. You might probably want to use a longer delay for sleep...

Comment: Sorry, you just answered when I was writing my comment. Yes, what you say may work. Now I have another problem. It seems that the alias `slowdonwtribler` does not work because it "gets" the PID number when I run the command `source .bashrc`, and at that point `tribler` is not running. I need to first run `tribler` then run `source .bashrc` and then run `slowdowntribler` for it to work. How I solve it?

Comment: `alias slowdowntribler='cpulimit -l 10 -p \`ps -ef | grep "tribler.exe" | grep -vw "grep" | awk "{print \$2}"\`'` might work... The problem is that your alias definition will immediately evaluate the expression you use for getting the PID. The changed should defer the evaluation...

Comment: I understand that the alias definition will immediately evaluate the expression. What do you mean by "The changed..." ? How I avoid that the expression is immediately evaluated?

Comment: The bash will evaluate the `command` in `alias name="command"` but not in `alias name='command'`. So I proposed you to change it (BTW: in the other two `alias`es, you have used `'` instead of `"`...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8503/discussion-between-rayo-hauno-and-abrixas2)

Comment: Correction: It must be `alias slowdowntribler='cpulimit -l 10 -p \`ps -ef | grep "tribler.exe" | grep -vw "grep" | awk "{print \\$2}"\`'`.